# Cannot figure this out C programming

Tags: c

The program is supposed to remove everything but the letters and create a new string which will have only the letters in upper-case.

However, it is not printing the results.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *remove_up(char input[])
{
    char *new_str = (char *) malloc(strlen(input) + 1);
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    while (i < strlen(input))
    {
        if (((input[i]) >= 65 && (input[i]<=90)) || ((input[i]>=97) && (input[i]<=122)))
        {
            new_str[j]= toupper(input[i]);
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        else i++;
    }
    return new_str;
}

int main()
{
    char str_1[100];
    char str_2[100];
    printf("Enter first word: ");
    fgets(str_1, sizeof(str_1), stdin);
    printf("Enter second word: ");
    fgets(str_2, sizeof(str_2), stdin);


    char *up_str_1 =(char *) malloc(strlen(str_1) + 1);
    char *up_str_2 =(char *) malloc(strlen(str_2) + 1);

    up_str_1= remove_up(str_1);
    up_str_2= remove_up(str_2);
    printf("%s", up_str_1);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%s", up_str_2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to have gotten cut off partway through the definition of `main` . . .

Comment: There are several problems with your program, but you don't appear to have put the whole thing here.

Comment: Sorry, I've posted the whole thing now. there wasn't anything missing aside from the return 0; and the brackets. But please let me know whats rong with it.

Comment: You're not printing anything.

Comment: There are no print statements in your program.  Where do you expect to get output?

Comment: I have added the output....It doesn't print...sorry must have forgotten to put it cus I was editing through it.

Comment: Don't use the ASCII values when comparing `char`s (65, 90, etc), compare against the actual `char`s (`'A'`, `'Z'`, etc). Your `malloc`s in `main` are also pointless and just create memory leaks, since straight after being initialized to the result of `malloc`, the pointers are being reassigned. Your code also doesn't compile, so that's one reason it's not going to print anything...

Comment: One more thing, turn your warnings up and include `<ctype.h>` for `toupper()`. The whole condition of your `if` statement can also be replaced by a single `isalpha(input[i])`.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few problems, but because this is tagged homework, I'll point them out but not give you the answer.

First of all, this doesn't do what you think:

```
int i, j = 0;
```

j will be initialized, but i probably won't start at 0. You need to initialize i to 0 as well.

Next, there's a typo - you missed a closing `]` at `(input[i<=122)`.

Finally, based on your answers to the questions, you probably aren't printing the result anyway: look up `printf()` or `cout` or whatever you prefer to use for outputting values.

Comment: It's C, so he can't use cout.  However, he's apparently given it a .cpp extension because he's declaring up_str_1 and up_str_2 inline rather than at the beginning of main().

Comment: Sorry, I understood and fixed the other points, but I don't understand your last point

Comment: @A_1_615: It does work if you initialize `i` to 0, fix the syntax error and have your compiler let you declare `up_str_1`/`2` in the middle of the scope. You'll also want `<ctype.h>` for `toupper`.

Comment: I assume you're working now? If I copy-paste your latest code and add <ctype.h> it seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't print results because you haven't used any print statements to show what comes back from your calls to remove_up.

To understand what is going on in your remove_up function, you need to understand this:

http://www.asciitable.com/

This code:

```
if (((input[i]) >= 65 && (input[i]<=90)) || ((input[i]>=97) && (input[i<=122)))
```

Is checking to see if a character is an alphabetic character in the ascii character set between these two ranges.  Look at the link above.  If it is in this set it's converting it to upper (redundant for half the data) and saving the result in your newly malloc'd string.

Problems:
 1. You never set a null terminator in "new_str"
 2. You never seem to free anything (though in this code it is trivial, in real code you could create problems, i.e. memory leaks).
 3. "i" is redundant in the while loop.  It's in both the if and else...
 4. Rethink how you're using malloc (you probably don't want to use it this way in your custom functions unless you're going to cleanup after yourself)

There is probably more I'm missing, but that should help you see some problems.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your use of parenths - you have more than needed.  You are also missing a ']' in that if statement.  Surprised it compiles.

Comment: Sorry that was an error when I was copying and pasting it onto here...all brackets were properly entered when I was compiling in my IDE.

Comment: thanks for the help...I have figured it out :)...should I close this post...??

Answer (score 0):

change `int i, j = 0;` to `int i = 0, j = 0;`. Your `i` was initialized with a garbage value greater than `strlen(input)`, and hence never entered the `while` loop.